Having a hard time removing duplicates between separate columns after merging dataframes in pandas
I'm comparing to Excel sheets and I created dataframes from an identical column from each file. I'm trying to output the compared dataframes to a new excel file however I only want the unique values from each column (a last week vs what changed this week kind of deal). The columns themselves will never have any duplicate data and .drop_duplicates isn't giving the desired outcome.
Is there a method or argument I'm missing to make this work?
Here's my script:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.read_excel('weeklyreport1.xlsx', index_col=None, na_values=['NA'], usecols="AH")
df2 = pd.read_excel('weeklyreport2.xlsx', index_col=None, na_values=['NA'], usecols="AH")

df_merged = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='inner', left_index=True, right_index=True, suffixes=('_previous_week', '_current_week'))
final = df_merged.drop_duplicates(subset=['hostname_previous_week', 'hostname_current_week'], keep=False)

final.to_excel('weeklychanges.xlsx')


This is what I get

What I want


the dataframes that you merge should be without the duplicate data when merging
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'src_host': ['pc2', 'pc3', 'pc4', 'pc5', 'pc6', 'pc7']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'src_host': ['pc1', 'pc2', 'pc3', 'pc4', 'pc7', 'pc8']})

df = pd.merge(
    df1.drop(df1[df1['src_host'].isin(df2['src_host'])].index).reset_index(drop=True),
    df2.drop(df2[df2['src_host'].isin(df1['src_host'])].index).reset_index(drop=True),
    left_index=True, right_index=True, suffixes=('_previous_week', '_current_week')
)

output:
  src_host_previous_week src_host_current_week
0                    pc5                   pc1
1                    pc6                   pc8

But you have to understand that this is good only for the src_host columns, there is no special reason for pc5 to be in the same row as pc1 and not pc8, and if there are other columns then the logic of your request has to be questioned.

Ok that makes more sense. Pardon my lack of experience. Question, the values being referenced(pc2,pc3,etc) are just from a tester doc to achieve the desired output. The actual document that will be compared with have significantly more entries under each column. Will I have to reference every value as you did above? Or is there a better way to reference anything in a column regardless of the number of rows? Thank you!
